# React Typescript: Ant Design Table Rerender specific Column

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, antd

Im mutating my `datasource` State `"this.state.question"` but the Table Column `"Actions"` dont rerender.

```
this.setState(currentState => ({
   ...currentState,
   question: currentState.question.map((item) => {
      if (item.no !== data.item1.no) return item;
         return {
            ...item,
            ...data.item1
         }
      })
}))
```

Column that should change:

```
{ title: "Actions", render: (record: ModelClass) => {
   return (
      <Space>
         <Button
            type="primary"
            disabled={record.deactivated} //<- nothing happens
         />
      </Space >
   )
}},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mutate state.

Quick glance tells me your code should look something like this:

```
if (this.state.responseMessage.successful) {
   this.setState(currentState => ({
      ...currentState,
      question: currentState.question.map((q) => {
        if(q.no !== data.item1.no) return q;
        return {
           ...q,
           ...data.item1
        }
      })
   }))
}
```

Comment: It only works halfway with your code. If the value from ```deactivated``` is true and I run the function (so ```deactivated``` becomes false) then the ```Button``` is going active and pressable but not the other way round.

Comment: Just found out, that the fetch is already broken and always returning false for ```deactivated```